XCode: error: attach by pid '1091' failed -- attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process
I'm running a flutter project on physical device (IOS 17.5.1)
Xcode version: 15.4
MacOS version: Sonoma 14.5
Chip: Apple M3 Pro
The app runs perfectly on Simulators but when i attach it to physical device the app installed successfully but when it initialize and a white screen shows, Xcode fires an error like this:

What i have tried:

sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable

Restart both devices and changed cable

Turn off Debug Executable

Delete App and run again

Clean build folder from Xcode

flutter clean && flutter pub get && flutter run


I've been suffering from this issue for three days!

In my case doing both these things in Edit Scheme -> Run fixed the issue:

unchecking 'Debug executable'
adding an environment variable IDEPreferLogStreaming with value YES



In my case the problem was that i was using a distribution profile to debug an app on iPad.
If you use manually managed signing this can happen, you simply have to create a development profile and use it to debug the app, if you use automatic signing this issue will probably never happen.
Xcode is not sufficiently smart to warn you about that.
Hope this can help someone
